# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@orange/redux/lib/services/actionsBack.service'. Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 con TypeScript como lenguaje de Script, y me ha surgido el siguiente error testeando uno de los componentes.
Actualmente llevo unos 5 meses desarrollando en Angular 8, y es el primer contacto que tengo con JavaScript ya que anteriomente me dedicaba al desarrollo movil nativo en Android con Java.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@orange/redux/lib/services/actionsBack.service.d.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\mlucassa\ANGULAR_PROYECTS\detalle-terminal-library-typescript (3)\node_modules\@orange\redux\lib\services\actionsBack.service.d.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (https://goo.gl/jB3GVv).
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\mlucassa\ANGULAR_PROYECTS\detalle-terminal-library-typescript (3)\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at C:\Users\mlucassa\ANGULAR_PROYECTS\detalle-terminal-library-typescript (3)\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
 @ ./src/lib/components/escaparate-banner/escaparate-banner.component.spec.ts 11:30-89
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

El archivo spec.ts es el siguiente:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { TerminalesData } from './../../models/terminales-model';
import { OrangeApi } from '@orange/redux';
import { CurrentDataService } from './../../services/current-data.service';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { EscaparateBannerComponent } from './escaparate-banner.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
//import { BackService } from '@orange/redux/lib/services/actionsBack.service';
import { BackService } from '@orange/redux/lib/services/actionsBack.service.d';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('EscaparateBannerComponent', () => {
  let component: EscaparateBannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EscaparateBannerComponent>;

  //TODO: CREAR CONST DE BACKERVICE

  beforeEach(async(() => {

//TDO: Recuperar rodos los parametro del backkService y pasarselos

    const backServiceStub = () => ({
      getBackService: () => Observable.of({data: 'backServiceStub'}),
      setBackService: (campaignPrints, customerManagement, 
        activationAndConfiguration,
        agreement, 
        productOrdering,
        bucketBalance,
        CustomerBill,
        interaction,
        userManagement,
        psp,
        communication,
        repository,
        shoppingCart,
        histogram,
        platforms,
        agencies,
        cycles,
        billing,
        customers,
        nofriendlyPorttfolio,
        friendlyPortfolio,
        reports,
        aresLdap,
        serviceQualification,
        productOfferingQualificationEffects,
        reservation,
        partyInteraction,
        troubleTicket,
        serviceTest,
        activityRegister,
        fmmCustomerManagement,
        surcharge,
        commercialBills,
        irisRecommendation,
        fmmaccountmanagement) => ({
        subscribe: () => ({ unsubscribe: () => ({}) })
      }),
    });


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [EscaparateBannerComponent],
      providers: [CurrentDataService,
                  OrangeApi,
                  {
                    provide: BackService,
                    useFactory: backServiceStub
                  },],
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}),HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]) ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EscaparateBannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
  });
  //TODO: Probar otros componentes hast ver como resolver error ActionsBack.service.

    describe('getBannerModuleData', () => {
      it('should be called', () => {
        const data = {
          imageEscritorio: '',
          imageMovilPerson: '',
          nameBannerDesk: '',
          nameBannerMobile:'',
          showForm: ''
        }
        
        component.moduleData = new TerminalesData(data);
        component.getBannerModuleData();
        expect(component.getBannerModuleData).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
   /*
    fit('makes expected calls', () => {
       const bannerPersonality = '';
       const spy = spyOn(component, 'getBannerModuleData').and.callThrough();
       component.getBannerModuleData();
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });*/
   });
```

Y el código del componente como tal es el siguiente:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { bannerDevice } from '../../models/banner-model';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { CurrentDataService } from '../../services/current-data.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { takeUntil, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'orange-escaparate-banner',
  templateUrl: './escaparate-banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./escaparate-banner.component.scss']
})
export class EscaparateBannerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() moduleData: any = null;
  public onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();


  public data;
  public imageEscritorio = '';
  public imageMovil = '';
  public imageEscritorioPerson = '';
  public imageMovilPerson = '';
  public nameBannerDesk = '';
  public nameBannerMobile = '';
  public showForm = false;
  modeloIdTelefono;


  constructor(private currentDataService: CurrentDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = new bannerDevice(this.moduleData);
      this.getCurrentData();
  }

  getCurrentData() {
    let verificador = true;
    this.currentDataService.getCurrentData().pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.shoppingCart && data.shoppingCart.devices && data.shoppingCart.devices.cartItem[0].id && verificador) {
        this.modeloIdTelefono = data.shoppingCart.devices.cartItem[0].id; 
        verificador=false;
        this.getBannerModuleData();// id del terminal
      }
    });
    
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onDestroy$.next();
    this.onDestroy$.complete();
  }
  getBannerModuleData() {
    this.imageEscritorio = _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannerdesk.image_bloblink_', '') || _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannerdesk.url', '');
    this.imageMovil = _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannermobile.image_bloblink_', '') || _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannermobile.url', '');
    this.nameBannerDesk = _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannerdesk.name', 'null');
    this.nameBannerMobile = _.get(this.data, 'listBannerDevice[0].bannermobile.name', '');

    const data = this.searchBanner(this.modeloIdTelefono);
    if (data) {
      this.imageEscritorioPerson = _.get(data, 'bannerdesk.image_bloblink_', '') || _.get(data, 'bannerdesk.url', '');
      this.imageMovilPerson = _.get(data, 'bannermobile.image_bloblink_', '') || _.get(data, 'bannermobile.url', '');
      this.showForm = true;
    } else if (this.nameBannerDesk === this.nameBannerMobile) {
      this.imageEscritorio;
      this.imageMovil;
      this.showForm = true;
    } else {
      this.showForm = false;
    }
  }
  searchBanner(name: string) {
    let data;
    for (const obj of this.data.listBannerDevice) {
      if (obj.name === name) {
        data = obj;
        break;
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudar si saben por donde van los tiros,  si es así, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Intenta borrando la carpeta `node_modules` y haz un `npm install` sobre el proyecto para volver a instalar todas las dependencias.

Comment: ya lo he probado, porque se trata de una librería concreta del proyecto que se instala en el node_modules, pero no tira. Además de borrar el node_modules, he borrado tambien el package-lock.json y he limpiado la cache con npm cache clean --force

Comment: Por el mensaje y lo que acabas de decir, supongo que la librería esta mal. Hiciste alguna actualización recientemente? De la librería o de angular?

Comment: A ver si que recuerdo hacer algun update de npm, y de angular no lo recuerdo ahora, pero puede ser. Debería restablecer las versiones anteriores??

Comment: Intentalo. Si antes funcionaba, y ahora no, puede ser eso. Que version de angular-cli estas usando?